# Python lambda function into php

Tags: php, python, lambda

I need to recreate this python lambda function into php function:

```
indexes.sort(key=lambda x: (x["index"], x["tag"], x["priority"]))
```

Can you help me please?

thank you!

Comment: Do you need the lambda function or do you need the whole line of code?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `usort` to sort by an anonymous function;

```
usort($index, function($a, $b) {
  $order = array('index', 'tag', 'priority');
  foreach($order as $name) {
    if($a[$name] < $b[$name]) return -1;
    if($a[$name] > $b[$name]) return  1;
  }
  return 0;
});
```